# Telephone headset adaptor weak microphone and speaker sound

Tags: microphone, adapter, telephone, headphones, trs

I have made a simple adaptor for a telephone P4C4 -- RJ9 -- separate headset output (The wiring diagram of a telephone handset can be viewed in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#4P4C)) to two TRS jack for an ordinary headset with two TRS plugs for mic and speaker using different articles like this [link](https://www.einhorn-net.de/headset/index_e.html).
(however without using the 500ohm resistor for the speaker).

The speaker and microphone work but the sound is a bit low for the speakers of the headset (even in the highest settings for sound output of the telephone) and the microphone is very much lower at picking up the voice.

- How can I improve the sound quality of this headset?
- Is the 500ohm resistor really necessary (I have read that without it
  the speakers are damaged in the long run, however there are many
  products available online that don't seem to have such a
  resistor)
- Is the 500ohm resistor in any way related to the problem of sound
  quality?

---update---
The headset model and brand is [JEQANG JH-808](https://shopee.com.my/High-fidelity-sound-JEQANG-JH-808-Full-Size-stereo-PC-headset-headphone-i.42421664.5613046903) and its internal mic picture is this:
[image]

The adaptor wiring is like this:
Speaker jack: The red wire of the telephone output is attached to jack's sleeve, the green wire of the telephone output is attached to jack's tip and ring.
Mic jack: The black wire of the telephone output is attached to the other jack's sleeve, and the yellow wire is attached to its tip.

Comment: You do not show what kind or size for the microphone and speakers.

Comment: It is a standard pc stereo headset with the mic integrated inside the sound volume control in the cable.

Comment: There is no "standard pc stereo headset". Include all of the information requested and add a schematic of the actual circuit you built. Don't ask us to click on an arcane link.

Comment: Some "standard" mic and ears headsets use a MEMS mic with preamp and other "standard" mic and ears headsets use an electret mic without a preamp. The preamp amplifies the mic. Some "standard" headsets use 32 ohm speakers with rare earth expensive magnets for good sensitivity and other "standard" headsets use 600 ohm speakers with cheap low sensitivity speakers.